# Non-XML version of <cache:annotation-driven /> 

Tags: spring, caching, configuration

To get the annotation-based caching-magic to work with Spring, one need to have a declaration in xml, like this:
`<cache:annotation-driven />`

How can I get the caching system configured programmatically?

This is what I have. I want to get rid of the `@ImportResource` and the XML file.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:cache-context.xml")
public class DI_EhCache {

    /**
     * Create cache object for various cachable methods and add to EhCache Manager.
     * 
     * @return EhCacheManager
     */
    @Bean
    EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager() {
        EhCacheCacheManager ehcm = new EhCacheCacheManager();        
        CacheManager cm = CacheManager.create();

        Cache station = new Cache("station", 1, false, true, 0, 10);
        cm.addCache(station);

        ehcm.setCacheManager(cm);

        return ehcm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring 3.1 RC2 added the `@EnableCaching` annotation, which wasn't present in RC1. This annotation is the equivalent of `<cache:annotation-driven />`, and is added to your `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class DI_EhCache {
```

Rc2 doesn't seem to have been announced, and the docs are not linked to from the site, but you can download it [here](http://www.springsource.com/download/community), and see the docs for `@EnableCaching` [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html).